# Yii2 generate model programmatically

Tags: php, yii, yii2, gii

How can i create action page that can call gii to  generate model programmatically?

I want to create a website that user can create there table.

Thanks

Comment: are you want user can create mysql table ??

Comment: yes. and automatic create model of that table

Comment: If you solve the table creation problem, then generating the model is easy - gii is available as a console command which you can run from php. If you ever change your mind about creating tables/models this way (it's pretty unsafe), consider [entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe ! but if you want to doing this I think you should create 2 models.

1. A model for generate a form
2. A model can migrate and run (or call) it from your code (not console)

Read the following links :

- [Dynamic Form](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform)
- [Yii2 Migration Model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html)